# Как зарегистрировать собственный логгер с анонимным параметром в список сервисов ASP.NET приложения?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6

У меня есть веб приложение на razor pages и кастомный логгер, который записывает сообщение в текстовый файл.

```
public class CustomLogger<T> : ICustomLogger<T>
    {
        private readonly string _pathToLogs;

        public void WriteLog(T type, ClaimsPrincipal userModel, string message)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(
                    path: $"{_pathToLogs}\\<<Путь к файлу>>",
                    contents: typeof(T) + "\n" + message
                    );
        }

        public CustomLogger(string pathToLogs)
        {
            _pathToLogs = pathToLogs;
            if(!Directory.Exists(pathToLogs))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToLogs);
        }
    }

    public interface ICustomLogger<in T>
    {
        public void WriteLog(ClaimsPrincipal userModel, string message) { }
    }
```

И мне нужно, чтобы он мог быть зарегистрирован как сервис для последующего инжекта в модель страницы. Хочу попробовать сделать простой аналог встроенного логгера, но именно с записью в файл :

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  
    public IndexModel(ICustomLogger<IndexModel> customLogger)
    {
        _customLogger = customLogger;
    }

    private readonly ICustomLogger<IndexModel> _customLogger;

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // Чтобы вот так это дело работало. 
        _customLogger.WriteLog(User, "Error message!");
    }

}
```

В сервисы регистрирую следующим образом

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomLogger<Type>>( 
    new CustomLogger<Type>(
        pathToLogs: builder.Environment.ContentRootPath + "\\Logs"
        )
    );
```

Разумеется, возникает ошибка "Невозможно разрешить сервис для типа ICustomLogger<Класс страницы>" при попытке внедрить этот сервис на любую другую страницу, чей класс я не поместил вместо Type. Я не понимаю как можно зарегистрировать свой логгер как сервис. Существует необузданное желание сделать именно так. Не хочется создавать инстанс на странице и не хочется отправлять сендер в методы. Ну и для общего развития интересно.

Я искал в сети возможные решения, но почти все из них списаны со статьи майкрософт по написанию логгера на основе ILogger, а те, что мне нужны не используют анонимный параметр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обобщённый интерфейс нельзя зарегистрировать при помощи общего типа **Type**, попробуйте регистрировать для каждого типа страниц отдельно:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomLogger<IndexModel>>(new CustomLogger<IndexModel>(pathToLogs: builder.Environment.ContentRootPath + "\\Logs"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomLogger<OtherModel>>(new CustomLogger<OtherModel>(pathToLogs: builder.Environment.ContentRootPath + "\\Logs"));
```